# Why does my oracle statement run differently on a windows database than linux?

Tags: database, windows, oracle10g, alias, redhat

I don't know where to begin to debug this.
Some developers have been writing some pl/sql code locally on their Windows machines that complete fine using Oracle 10.2.0.1.0 - 64bit.  When it gets to production, which is Red Hat 5.3 and running 10.2.0.2.0, it gives me this error:

ORA-00904: "S"."BARSTREAMREFERENCEID": invalid identifier

Here is the gist of the code that is working in Windows:

```
EXECUTE IMMEDIATE('
  update candyman.CANDY_REFERENCES s
     set ( s.flavour, s.taste, s.colour, s.privateField3 ) =
         ( select * from
                ( select r.flavour, r.taste, r.colour, null
                    from candyman.FOO_REFERENCE_SET t
                    join candyman.FOO_REFERENCES r on r.fooReferenceID = t.fooReferenceID
                   where t.barStreamReferenceID = s.barStreamReferenceID
                order by r.colour )
            where rownum = 1 )
   where privateField3 is not null
     and exists
         ( select 1
             from candyman.FOO_REFERENCE_SET t
             join candyman.FOO_REFERENCES r on r.fooReferenceID = t.fooReferenceID
            where t.barStreamReferenceID = s.barStreamReferenceID )
');
```

I know... they should have updated their Oracle versions with the rest of the company and be developing on the same version as production, but it is too late and I can't control them...

Any ideas are greatly appreciated.

Comment: That means that there is no BARSTREAMREFERENCEID column in the candyman.CANDY_REFERENCES in your production environment - have the developers have added it in the dev environment but not prod?

Comment: I see the column in production.

Comment: Could there be a permissions issue that prevents the code from seeing the column? (Oracle always uppercases column names in error messages, doesn't it?)

Comment: Good question. Unfortunately I see other statements being executing on the same table as the same user in the script.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See [this AskTom thread](http://asktom.oracle.com/pls/asktom/f?p=100:11:0%3a%3a%3a%3aP11_QUESTION_ID:1853075500346799932):

> ANSI SQL has table references (correlation names) scoped to just one
>   level deep
>
> ...
>
> In version 10.2.0.1.0 this query works:
>
> select (select count(*) from (select * from scott.emp where ename =
>   dual.dummy)) from dual;
>
> ...
>
> that was a bug.
>
> it works in none of the terminal releases of 9i, 10g, or 11g

I'm a huge fan of developing locally.  One of the main benefits is that it's easier to configure and manage your local instance than a server.  I'm surprised that a developer would not want to use a *newer* version.

Comment: Well hot damn. I don't think it is a question of 'want', it is more like "I inherited this tower with Oracle set up already and am lazy" :)