# Accessing value from outer query to the sub query of inner query

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql, oracle11g

I have an issue while accessing data from outer query

```
        SELECT y.task_id,y.R,y.location_id,

         (SELECT COLUMN_VALUE FROM (

          SELECT ROWNUM R, B.* FROM TABLE(  

          SELECT VALUE FROM

          DATASET WHERE R=1) B) WHERE R =1) AS latitude,

         (SELECT COLUMN_VALUE FROM (

          SELECT ROWNUM R, A.* FROM TABLE(

          SELECT VALUE FROM

          DATASET WHERE R =y.R) A) WHERE R =2) AS longitude

     FROM DATASET y
```

while executing this i got an error like

`ORA-06553: PLS-306: wrong number or types of arguments in call to 'OGC_Y'`

But if i remove `WHERE R =y.R`, then it will give some out put. I cannot figure out the issue

Comment: possible duplicate of [Why does my oracle statement run differently on a windows database than linux?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13748795/why-does-my-oracle-statement-run-differently-on-a-windows-database-than-linux)

Answer (score 0):

Use a With clause?

With latitude as(SELECT COLUMN_VALUE FROM (

```
      SELECT ROWNUM R, B.* FROM TABLE(  

      SELECT VALUE FROM

      DATASET WHERE R=1) B) WHERE R =1), 
 longitude as (SELECT COLUMN_VALUE FROM (

      SELECT ROWNUM R, A.* FROM TABLE(

      SELECT VALUE FROM

      DATASET WHERE R =y.R) A) WHERE R =2
```

)
SELECT y.task_id, y.R, y.location_id, lat.column_value, lon.column_value
  FROM dataset y, latitude lat, longitude lon